# Including Classes without having to redefine

Tags: php

So I know that in order for a.class.php to be used within b.class.php I would need to have the a class included in the b class file. My question is this.
I have two classes files at the moment within my website platform. db.class.php and account.class.php

*db.class.php*

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings.php');
class db extends pdo{
    //Website Variables

    public $sitedb = '';
    public $siteconfig;
    public $sitesettings = array(
        'host'      => SITEHOST,
        'database'  => SITEDB,
        'username'  => SITEUSER,
        'password'  => SITEPASS,
    );
    public $realmdb = '';
    public $realmconfig;
    public $realmsettings = array(
        'host'      => REALMHOST,
        'database'  => REALMDB,
        'username'  => REALMUSER,
        'password'  => REALMPASS,
    );

    public function __construct(){

        $this->sitedb = new PDO(
            "mysql:host={$this->sitesettings['host']};" .
            "dbname={$this->sitesettings['database']};" .
            "charset=utf8",
            "{$this->sitesettings['username']}",
            "{$this->sitesettings['password']}"
        );
        $this->realmdb = new PDO(
            "mysql:host={$this->realmsettings['host']};" .
            "dbname={$this->realmsettings['database']};" .
            "charset=utf8",
            "{$this->realmsettings['username']}",
            "{$this->realmsettings['password']}"
        );
        $this->sitedb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->realmdb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

}
$db = new db();
```

*account.class.php*

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings.php');
class account extends db {
    public function Login() {
        $query = <<<SQL
        SELECT id
        FROM profile
        WHERE password = :password
SQL;
            $resource = $db->sitedb->prepare ( $query );
            $resource->execute( array(
                ':password' => sha1(strtoupper($_POST['email'].':'.$_POST['password'],
                ));
                $row_count = $resource->rowCount();
                echo $row_count;

        }
}
$account = new account();
```

This current format tells me that db cannot be redefined, however if I remove the requirement of including the settings file which has

```
foreach (glob("functions.d/*.class.php") as $class)
{
    include $class;
}
```

It then tells me that class db cannot be found. What way can I work around to have this work correctly?

Comment: class_existsI() api before include the class

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the best way to accomplish this was to keep the includes correctly and have all classes within the same file and within my include page utilizing classes have global $db or global $account depending on what I class function I was calling on.